# Querying Embedded document in MongoDB using Mongo Template

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have the above domain structure where I have list of Companies in the product and the aim is  not make entry in mongoDB when I have exact match for companies & `productId` already present in the DB.

```
@Entity
    public class Mobile {
        @Id
        private Integer id;
        private String imei;
        private Product productInfo;

        // ...
    }


    @Entity
    public class Product {
        @Id
        private Integer id;
        private String productId;
        private List<Company<?>> companies;

        // ...
    }


    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name= "samsung", value = Samsung.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name= "htc",value = Htc.class)})
    public class Company<T> implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8869676577723436716L;

        private T companyInfo;
        private String type;

        // ...
    }
```

I am using mongo template and I have tried to use find as shown below but id didn't work

```
template.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("product.companies").is(companList),Mobile.class);
```

Comment: try with `Criteria.where("product.companies").in(companList)`

Comment: I'm looking for the exact match of _companies_, in specific. So if I use _in_ it would check for list included in the _companyList_ not the exact match. Edited the post ,Thanks.

Comment: In that case, use `.all(companList)`